# Expiring authentication token in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm generating an authentication token using token = Devise.friendly_token. I want to know how I can expire this token in lets say 24hours ?

Answer (score 2):

In the intializers directory there should be a devise.rb file.

You can change the various options there.  I believe what you are looking for is one of the following

```
config.rememember_for = 24.hours
config.timeout_in = 24.hours
```

The first is related to :rememberable (the time user can go without being asked for credentials) and the second is related to :timeoutable (amount of time without activity before session times out).

Comment: will this even expire a custom authentication_token ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use particular JWT Authentication Ruby Gem, that fully complements 'Devise' with desired features for authentication, you may look at it on [github](https://github.com/Rezonans/jwt_authentication/blob/master/README.md).